# What is the right way to put HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm programming in PHP, but I don't think its the right way.

I'm programming something like this:

```
<?php
    $apple = 10
    if(apple >= 4){
        ?>
         <img src="Bladieblabla">
         <a href="Bladieblabla.bla">Biep</a>
        <?php
    }else{
        print "Awhh we don't have 4 apples";
    }
?>
```

Comment: why do you think its wrong?

Comment: This will do what you want

Comment: Your question reminded me of: "If I have 4 apples in one hand and 5 in the other, what do I have?" -- "Big hands."

Comment: I was taught to use that way in my PHP class at college.

It saves time on slash escaping every special character, it avoids conflicts between " and ' and it displays nicely/neatly in your text editor.

Short answer: you're doing it right! =)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that...You could use that way or you could use `echo` like in the answers below ;) I'm using both ways, depends of how large is HTML code, if it's short, sure echo it but if it's long write it as in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`echo`](http://php.net/echo), or [`print`](https://www.php.net/print) like this

```
if($apple > 5) {
     echo '<img src="Bladieblabla">';
     echo '<a href="Bladieblabla.bla">Biep</a>';
} else {
    print "Awhh we don't have 4 apples";
}
```

**Update:** Using `echo` only one time:

```
echo '<img src="Bladieblabla">
<a href="Bladieblabla.bla">Biep</a>';
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Can i use print too?

Comment: Yes, you can use print too

Comment: Isn't it much work for a big code?

Comment: that depends, you could use echo / print 1 time, like in the update..

Comment: Very thanks for all your comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $apple = 10;
    if(apple > 5){

        echo '<img src="Bladieblabla">';
        echo '<a href="Bladieblabla.bla">Biep</a>';

    }else{
        print "Awhh we don't have 4 apples";
    }
?>
```